# Alternative to PHP Include?

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include an external page onto my main home page of my website. However, when I use include_once or just php include alone, it throws this error at me:

```
Warning: require_once(../_inc/glob.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/radisite/public_html/panel/_frontend/requests.php on line 2
```

I don't want to use iFrame because then it slows my site down completely. Is there any other faster alternative for PHP includes? I've looked at other methods on here and they're confusing me to bits.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `include_once` instead of `require_once`. If the page does not load, it won't stop the script.

Comment: `include` and `request` takes milliseconds to call. Problem is on WHAT you are including there. And, please use `request` instead of `include`. Include shows warning when something goes "tits up", while require will give you an error. Problem is that on some servers the warnings are hidden and you will be lets in a dark, wondering "what the hell went wrong here".

Comment: This is the code I use:

<?php include_once('panel/_frontend/requests.php'); ?>

And it throws the above error.

Comment: I found that ajax includes worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem with the path of the file. Check your file path and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You may either specified a wrong path, or have problem with [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) setting; If you are sure your path is formed correctly, then either adjust `include_path`, or prefix your path with `dirname(__FILE__)` on PHP < 5.3 or `__DIR__` on PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 0):

use

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/yourfolder/".'glob.php')
```